# How to keep a statefull bean clean or reset during a @QuarkusTest?

Tags: integration-testing, quarkus, stateful

I test a statefull bean with a `@QuarkusTest`. It keeps a certain state. Obviously,  I would like to have a fresh bean for every test. At the moment, each test might modify he current state, which is the effective for a oncoming test. This is highly undersireable and breaks my tests.

Is there a way to force a new bean clean bean getting injected for every test when running a `@QuarkusTest`?

Eg. A very basic subscription service, which holds the current subscription to avoid double subscriptions:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class SubscriptionService {

    @Inject
    DeviceClient deviceClient;

    private final Set<String> subscribedDevices = new HashSet<>();

    public void subscribe(String deviceId, Consumer<RadarFrame> consumer){
        if(subscriptions.contains(deviceId)){
            return;
        }
        deviceClient.subscribe(deviceId, consumer);
        subscriptions.add(deviceId);
    }

    public void unsubscribe(String deviceId, Consumer<RadarFrame> consumer){
        deviceClient.unsubscribe(deviceId);
        subscriptions.remove(deviceId);
    }
}
```

I could manually unsubscribe the device after each test, which is a bad small as I use potention untested implemented logic for setup/teardown. It would be nice if a injected bean could be reinitialized before each test on a `@QuarkusTest`.
Or did I miss another clean option?

Comment: Can you show some example code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

`@ApplicationScoped` beans will be there for the entire life of the container.
The recommended way to do this is to create a `reset()` method in the bean to later be called in tests. With JUnit 5 this would be something like:

```
 @AfterEach
 void tearDown() {
    subscriptionService.reset();
 }
```

You can make that method package friendly to limit it's usage.

Comment: As it is a possibility, I would like to explore other options first as this means I write productive code for the sole reason of testing. I generally would like to avoid that.

Comment: Consider using `@Dependent` instead of `@ApplicationScoped`.  I assume this works because `@QuarkusTest` defines a new parent bean for each test and hence necessitates a new bean per dependent for each test.

I understand it is changing production code for the sake of tests however on deeper thought the problem experienced with testing the code is hinting at problems that are possible on production as well if that state is not necessarily shared